# How can I use figure in caption of a figure?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I need to include a small figure at the end of the original figure caption, is there any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: there's no need to use the `figure` environment.  `\includegraphics` can be used directly, but do provide a form of the caption text without the graphic to be used in the list of figures (if you have one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{{example-image-a}}
    \caption[Caption for list of figures.]{Whatever works. {\protect\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `mwe` package to provide full compilable MWEs with dummy images comes with the package.

Comment: nice package (mwe).

Comment: A genuine product of TeX.SX thanks to Martin Scharrer.

Comment: There's no need to explicitly load `mwe` to use the images it provides.

Comment: @Gonzalo: there's no need if the package is installed. But if the package is not installed, loading it might trigger a more meaningful error message or an automatic package install procedure.